# Can I have more than one instance of some Django project configured in my system?

Tags: django, deployment, settings

I have requirement like this:
On one server(linux) I need to run 2 instances of the same Django project (the same name, different versions). I've noticed that there is some conflict with settings module (both projects use the same file, which of course is wrong).

Do you have some pointers how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the [well-known techniques](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) for selecting your settings module in your `.wsgi` file.